# How do i set cell colors to a grid that has dynamic columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i'm creating test results grid for K-9 blood tests. When a pet dog goes to the vet, vet takes some blood samples and for my case the vet performs two categories of blood test.

1. JOK-5
2. K9-DTR

in each blood test the vet tests for quantities of **OMG, PIGT, LBQ** and **BTR**. their quantities are in **mg/l** units. those tests performed in two separate days  01/21/2015 and 10/06/2014. the quantities will be placed on the cells as shown on image. The quantity value is in the property `MeasuredValue` of the json array in `data` variable.

[image]

this is a react component but don't worry about the react, the ajax for data and grid generation is done in the getData() function.

In the getData() data is assigned to a local variable and using the following code i assign data to rows.

```
        for(var n=0;n<arrayForRecords.length;n++){
            jQuery("#list483").jqGrid('addRowData', n + 1, arrayForRecords[n]);
        }
```

in the grid function gridComplete() i do the following process to place data in each cell of each row

```
            gridComplete:function(){

                //array consists of old rows and new row
                var dataArray = $('#list483').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //
                // get catName and ShortName combination for the newly added row then search  arrayForRecords
                // and get their labdates array then place the MeasuredValues on the matching cells.
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                if(dataArray.length>0){
                    var lastrow=dataArray[dataArray.length-1];

                    var catName = lastrow.CatName;
                    var shortName=lastrow.ShortName;
                    var myLabDates =[];

                    $(arrayForRecords).each(function(index,item){
                        if(item.CatName==catName & item.ShortName==shortName){
                            //get labDates collection
                            myLabDates= item.LabDatesandValues;
                        }
                    });

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(myLabDates));

                    //iterate through the labdates and values and set the values in the matching cell.
                    $(myLabDates).each(function(index,item){
                        if(catName=="Immunization Questions"){

                            //I did not want to check ChoiceText becuase it can be only 'Yes/No/Dont know'
                            $('#list483').jqGrid('setCell', dataArray.length, item.LB, item.CT);
                        }
                        else if(catName=="Onsite Testing"){

                            //when choice text empty put MeasureValue as value in cell
                            if(item.CT==''){
                                //put measure value
                                $('#list483').jqGrid('setCell', dataArray.length, item.LB, item.MV);
                            }
                            else{//when Choice Text has a value put ChoiceText value in cell

                                $('#list483').jqGrid('setCell', dataArray.length, item.LB, item.CT);
                            }

                        }
                        else{//for all the other values

                            //If binary anser is 'POS/NEG' place POS/NEG as value in cell based on MV=1/0
                            if(item.BA=='POS/NEG'){

                                if(item.MV==1){
                                    $('#list483').jqGrid('setCell', dataArray.length, item.LB, 'POS');
                                }
                                else{
                                    $('#list483').jqGrid('setCell', dataArray.length, item.LB, 'NEG');
                                }
                            }//some other values also must insert Yes/No in cell these values are in 'prevention screens'
                            else if(item.BA=='Yes/No'){
                                if(item.MV==1){
                                    $('#list483').jqGrid('setCell', dataArray.length, item.LB, 'Yes');
                                }
                                else{
                                    $('#list483').jqGrid('setCell', dataArray.length, item.LB, 'No');
                                }
                            }
                            else{//for all the others place measurevalue directly on cell

                                $('#list483').jqGrid('setCell', dataArray.length, item.LB, item.MV);
                            }

                        }

                    })

                }

                //this places teh contents on cell row by row: add dates from setCell method.
                $(dataArray).each(function (index){

                 });

            }
```

the local data in json will be reformatted to a data structure that meets the grid structure and its done in this code: (the reformatted data for the grid structure is in the array `arrayForRecords` )

the reformatted data strucutre as follows:

`aRecord = {CategoryId:catID, CatName:foundCatName, ShortName:foundShortName, ReferenceMax:reference,Units:uom, LabDatesandValues:datesArray};`

`LabDatesandValues` has the following structure:
`{LB:item.LabDate, MV:measureValOperator, CT:item.ChoiceText, BA:trimmedBAValue, ABF: Abnormal}`

`LB, MV, CT, BA, ABF` properties assigned with the properties that comes from the original array in `data` variable. **ABF contains the abnormal value**

the code for reformatting as follows:

```
         success: function(data){

                //data from client:the url call is a dummy one. 
                var data = [{"CategoryId":63,"CatName":"K9-DTR","ShortName":"LBQ","ReferenceMax":null,"ReferenceMin":null,"RefRangeMax":null,"RefRangeMin":null,"LevelsID":null,"Label":null,"Min":null,"Max":null,"Points":null,"NewPoints":0,"Abnormal":1,"AbnormalFlag":null,"LDescription":null,"MDescription":null,"Email":"test@test.com","Units":"mg/l","BinaryAnswer":null,"MeasuresId":2286,"MeasuredValue":23.77,"LabDate":"01/21/2015","Operator":"","SortOrder":null,"AnswersQCID":null,"AnswersAuthorID":90889,"LabCorpID":"180062","NumOfDupes":0,"SortCat":0,"SortMeas1":null,"SortAnsLabDate":"\/Date(1421778600000)\/","ChoiceText":null},{"CategoryId":63,"CatName":"K9-DTR","ShortName":"BTR","ReferenceMax":null,"ReferenceMin":null,"RefRangeMax":null,"RefRangeMin":null,"LevelsID":null,"Label":null,"Min":null,"Max":null,"Points":null,"NewPoints":0,"Abnormal":0,"AbnormalFlag":null,"LDescription":null,"MDescription":null,"Email":"test@test.com","Units":"mg/l","BinaryAnswer":null,"MeasuresId":2286,"MeasuredValue":3.44,"LabDate":"10/06/2014","Operator":"","SortOrder":null,"AnswersQCID":null,"AnswersAuthorID":90889,"LabCorpID":"180062","NumOfDupes":0,"SortCat":0,"SortMeas1":null,"SortAnsLabDate":"\/Date(1412533800000)\/","ChoiceText":null},{"CategoryId":64,"CatName":"JOK-45","ShortName":"OMG","ReferenceMax":null,"ReferenceMin":null,"RefRangeMax":null,"RefRangeMin":null,"LevelsID":null,"Label":null,"Min":null,"Max":null,"Points":null,"NewPoints":0,"Abnormal":1,"AbnormalFlag":null,"LDescription":null,"MDescription":null,"Email":"test@test.com","Units":"mg/l","BinaryAnswer":null,"MeasuresId":2286,"MeasuredValue":0.9999,"LabDate":"10/06/2014","Operator":"","SortOrder":null,"AnswersQCID":null,"AnswersAuthorID":90889,"LabCorpID":"180062","NumOfDupes":0,"SortCat":0,"SortMeas1":null,"SortAnsLabDate":"\/Date(1412533800000)\/","ChoiceText":null},{"CategoryId":64,"CatName":"JOK-45","ShortName":"PIGT","ReferenceMax":null,"ReferenceMin":null,"RefRangeMax":null,"RefRangeMin":null,"LevelsID":null,"Label":null,"Min":null,"Max":null,"Points":null,"NewPoints":0,"Abnormal":0,"AbnormalFlag":null,"LDescription":null,"MDescription":null,"Email":"test@test.com","Units":"mg/l","BinaryAnswer":null,"MeasuresId":2286,"MeasuredValue":23.3,"LabDate":"10/06/2014","Operator":"","SortOrder":null,"AnswersQCID":null,"AnswersAuthorID":90889,"LabCorpID":"180062","NumOfDupes":0,"SortCat":0,"SortMeas1":null,"SortAnsLabDate":"\/Date(1412533800000)\/","ChoiceText":null}];

                //////////////////// this has unique set of dates //////////////////
                $(data).each(function(index,item){
                   tmpLabDates[index]=item.LabDate;
                    //tmpLabDates[index]=mon+'/'+dt+'/'+year;
                })

                $(data).each(function(index,item){
                    allShortNames[index]=item.ShortName;
                })

                $(data).each(function(index,item){
                    alldupGroups[index]=item.CatName;
                });

                allunqGroups=alldupGroups.filter(onlyUnique);

               //remove redundencies
               unqLabDates = tmpLabDates.filter( onlyUnique );
                allunqShortNames=allShortNames.filter(onlyUnique);

                var catID='';
                var reference='';
                var uom='';
                var aRecord='';

                //added:10/26/2016
                //add an empty to unqLabDates so it generates a column on Lab dates side.this will prevent
                //overllaping of from/to datepickers boxes with static column headers.
                if(data.length==0){
                    unqLabDates.push('');
                }

                //manually reconstructing the data from DB with each row to have its own labdates collection
                    for(var i=0;i<allunqGroups.length;i++){

                        for(var j=0;j<allunqShortNames.length;j++){

                            $(data).each(function(index,item){

                                if(allunqGroups[i]==item.CatName)
                                {
                                    if(allunqShortNames[j]==item.ShortName)
                                    {
                                        //prints catId accurately
                                        catID=item.CategoryId;


                                        //settting the Reference column value based on ReferenceMin and ReferecenMax
                                        if(  (item.ReferenceMin == null) | item.ReferenceMax==null){
                                            reference='-';
                                            // alert('hello');
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            reference = item.ReferenceMin.toString()+'-'+item.ReferenceMax.toString();
                                        }

                                        //reference= item.ReferenceMax;    //if RefernceMax and Min not null concat min-max value for reference
                                        uom=item.Units;


                                        //this will add measure value with its operator symbol
                                        var measureValOperator = item.Operator + item.MeasuredValue.toString();

                                        if(item.BinaryAnswer!=null){
                                            var trimmedBAValue=item.BinaryAnswer.trim();
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            var trimmedBAValue=item.BinaryAnswer;
                                        }

                                        var labDateAndMeasureValue = {LB:item.LabDate, MV:measureValOperator, CT:item.ChoiceText, BA:trimmedBAValue, ABF: Abnormal};
                                        //var labDateAndMeasureValue = {LB:mon+'/'+dt+'/'+year, MV:item.MeasuredValue};

                                        //repeated ones are the dates:store all labdates for teh current matching combination.
                                        datesArray.push(labDateAndMeasureValue);

                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            var foundCatName=allunqGroups[i];
                            var foundShortName=allunqShortNames[j];

                            //this condition prevents adding blank arrays for labdates. also this stops the short name repeat in a catname
                            if(datesArray.length >0){

                               //'ReferenceMax' property here is string concatenation of ReferenceMin and ReferenceMax (see above).
                                aRecord = {CategoryId:catID, CatName:foundCatName, ShortName:foundShortName, ReferenceMax:reference,Units:uom, LabDatesandValues:datesArray};

                                //add object to the unqiue objects array
                                arrayForRecords.push(aRecord);

                                //clear the labdates array for the labdates of the next set of CatName and ShortName
                                datesArray=[];
                            }

                        }
                    }

//code to configure grid after this

}
```

the grid places the `measureValue` in the matching cell.

what i need to do is there is property in json array called `Abnormal`. when `Abnormal` == 1 the cell of its 'measureValue' must be colored in `red` and `underlined`. when `Abnormal`== 0 cell color must be set to default and remove underlining.

**ABF property contains the abnormal value**

How do achieve this?

Here is the complete code for the component is in [jsfiddle-k9](https://jsfiddle.net/56060pqa/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I full understand your code, but it seems that you try to implement pivot table. I'd recommend you to use `jqPivot` method. It's described in old version of jqGrid (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#pivot_grid)), but the old implementation contains many bugs. Because of that I full rewrote the code in free jqGrid, trying to hold the backward compatibility. I added many new features described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9). It allows to reduce the code for creating [**the demo**](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotWithCellAttr.htm) with the following code

```
$("#list483").jqGrid("jqPivot",
    data,
    {
        frozenStaticCols: true,
        xDimension: [
            {/*x0*/ dataName: "CatName", width: 200, label: "Lab Test" },
            {/*x1*/ dataName: "ShortName", skipGrouping: true },
            {/*x2*/ dataName: "ReferenceMin", hidden: true, skipGrouping: true },
            {/*x3*/ dataName: "ReferenceMax", width: 80, align: "center",
                label: "Reference", skipGrouping: true,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    // x2 - ReferenceMin, x3 - ReferenceMax
                    return rowObject.x2 === null || rowObject.x3 === null ?
                        "-" :
                        String(rowObject.x2) + "-" + String(cellvalue);
                }
            },
            {/*x4*/ dataName: "Units", width: 50, align: "center", skipGrouping: true },
            {/*x5*/ dataName: "Abnormal", hidden: true, skipGrouping: true }
        ],
        yDimension: [{
            dataName: "LabDate",
            sorttype: "date"
        }],
        aggregates: [{
            member: "MeasuredValue",
            cellattr: function(rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                if (rawObject != null && rawObject.x5 === 1) {//x5 - Abnormal
                    return ' class="ui-state-error"';
                }
            },
            aggregator: "max"
        }]
    },
// grid options
    {
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, width: 90 },
        shrinkToFit: false,
        useUnformattedDataForCellAttr: false,
        //autoresizeOnLoad: true,
        autoResizing: { compact: true },
        /*rowattr: function (item) {
            if (item.x5 === 1) {
                return {"class": "ui-state-error"};
            }
        },*/
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ["x1"],
            groupColumnShow: [false],
            groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>']
        },
        width: 450,
        pager: true,
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 100, "10000:All"],
        caption: "<b>K-9 Test Results</b>"
    }
);
```

which produces the results like on the picture below

[image]

If I comment (or remove) the block with

```
cellattr: function(rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
    if (rawObject != null && rawObject.x5 === 1) {//x5 - Abnormal
        return ' class="ui-state-error"';
    }
}
```

and uncomment the block

```
rowattr: function (item) {
    if (item.x5 === 1) {
        return {"class": "ui-state-error"};
    }
}
```

we get the results like

[image]

See [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotWithCellAttr1.htm).

**UPDATED:** [One more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotWithCellAttr2.htm) shows new possibility of `jqPivot`, which I just implemented. It allows to use `additionalProperty: true` instead of `hidden: true, skipGrouping: true` in `xDimension`. The last demo uses

```
xDimension: [
    {/*x0*/ dataName: "CatName", width: 200, label: "Lab Test" },
    {/*x1*/ dataName: "ShortName", skipGrouping: true },
    {/*x2*/ dataName: "ReferenceMin", additionalProperty: true },
    {/*x3*/ dataName: "ReferenceMax", width: 80, align: "center",
        label: "Reference", skipGrouping: true,
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            // x2 - ReferenceMin, x3 - ReferenceMax
            return rowObject.x2 === null || rowObject.x3 === null ?
                "-" :
                String(rowObject.x2) + "-" + String(cellvalue);
        }
    },
    {/*x4*/ dataName: "Units", width: 50, align: "center", skipGrouping: true },
    {/*x5*/ dataName: "Abnormal", additionalProperty: true }
]
```

The main advantage of this: removing unneeded hidden columns from DOM of the grid. The corresonding properties will be saved in the local data and can be used for example in custom formatters, `cellattr` or `rowattr`. See [the wiki artikle](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/additionalProperties-option-makes-unneeded-hidden-columns-in-local-scenario) for additional information about `additionalProperties`.

Comment: it solutions with a pivot but at the moment i cannot change my current grid to pivot. My grid looks like a pivot but its not the grid im using is 'grouped header row config' sample but i have customized it to be 'Frozen Column with Group header' where LabTest, reference, units frozen and teh dates are dynamically generated with a horizontal scroll bar. this scroll bar thus only scrolls the dates horizontally. Is there away to set the cell colors based on the value in property abnormal?

Comment: @ANP: Sorry, but your code https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/56060pqa/3/ and my demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotWithCellAttr2.htm uses the same grids, the same columns will be used in grouping and the same columns are frozen. I uses your original data. Non-frozen columns will be **dynamically** generated from `LabDate` exactly like in your case.  The main difference is the performance. Try to add 1000 rows in input data using my code and youth and you will see the difference.

Comment: @ANP: If you will hold your code that you should **never ever fill the grid calling `addRowData` in the loop**  and **never ever modify every row in `gridComplete` or `loadComplete`**. Data added in the old jqGrid 4.6 by `addRowData` will be added slowly and will be not processed by `cellattr` and `rowattr`. Free jqGrid fixed the bug. Moreover free jqGrid contains large performance improvement of the frozen columns implementation. The only way to fix your problem in jqGrid 4.6: the usage of `data` input parameter of the grid.

Comment: thanks for the reply, you meant by data input parameter is to pass the URL directly on to grid to grids URL property? If you are saying to pass the URL directly onto grid then the reason i did not pass, the original data source i use that comes from DB has about 900 records and there are so many repeated dates. So in order to have unique date columns, i need to remove the duplicates. Can this process be done within the grid?

Comment: @ANP: Sorry, but I can't follow your last comment. I never wrote about the usage of URL, but you can use it too in case of usage `jqPivot`: see [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30795988/315935). The "removing of the duplicates" is the aggregation of data: the main goal of pivot tables. During the aggregation pivot use the aggregator operation (I used `aggregator: "max"`, but one can use `count`, `sum` and so on) over all items with the same `yDimension` (the same `LabDate`). I recommend you to read [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9)