# JQgrid Pivot : jquery.jqGrid.src.js:11851 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'grouping' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm facing an issue when binding JSON data to JQGrid Pivot, on first load it will throw the below error and fails to load the Jqgrid. When tried for the second time, below error will not occur and successfully loads the grid.

[image]

JQ Grid Code :

```
if ($("#rdbImperial").prop("checked")) {
    grid.jqGrid('jqPivot',
        gridData, {
            xDimension: [
            {
                dataName: 'MaterialID',
                label: 'MaterialID',
                width: 100
            },
            {
                dataName: 'ZDESMaterialID',
                label: 'ZDES Material ID',
                width: 150
            },

            {
                dataName: 'MaterialDescription',
                label: 'Material Description',
                width: 100
            }

            ],
            yDimension: [{
                dataName: 'DimensionCodeWithDescription',
                converter: MyConverter,

            }],
            aggregates: [
                {
                    formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 4 },
                    label: "Imperial",
                    width: 160,
                    align: "right",
                    aggregator: "sum",
                    summaryType: "sum",
                    member: "ImperialWithoutUnit",
                    formatter: MyFormatterI,
                }
            ],
            //rowTotals: true,
            //colTotals: true,
            //frozenStaticCols: true
        },
        // grid options
        {
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            loadOnce: true,
            emptyrecords: 'No record(s) to display',
            width: "100%",
            height: "Auto",
            multipleGroup:true,
            rowNum: 50,
            caption: "Grid View - Part Number(s) search result",
            loadComplete: function () {
                $('#gridPartNumberSearchGridView').css("max-width", "100%");
            },
            gridComplete: function () {
                if (window.IsMultiple == true) {
                    $('#divDisplayMessage').css("display", "block");
                }
                else {
                    $('#divDisplayMessage').css("display", "none");
                }
            }
        });

    $('#gridPartNumberSearchGridView').jqGrid('groupingRemove');
    $("#gridPartNumberSearchGridView").hideCol("MaterialID");
}
```

where

```
var MyConverter = function (val) 
{ return (val.replace(/"/g, "")).replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\s/g, '_'); 
}

var MyFormatterI = function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    //debugger;
    var storedString = localStorage.getItem('myEventsArray');
    var parsedObject = JSON.parse(storedString);
    if (options.rowId != "") {
        if (cellvalue === undefined) { return ''; }
        else if (cellvalue.toString().length > 10) { window.IsMultiple = true; return "*"; }
        else if (isNaN(cellvalue) && cellvalue != undefined && parsedObject!=null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < parsedObject.length ; i++) {
                if ((parsedObject[i].MaterialDescription == rowObject["MaterialDescription"])
                    && (parsedObject[i].ZDESMaterialID == rowObject["ZDESMaterialID"])
                    && ((parsedObject[i].DimensionCodeWithDescription.replace(/\s/g, '_') == options.colModel.name) || (parsedObject[i].DimensionCodeWithDescription.replace(/\s/g, '_') + '_sum_0' == options.colModel.name))
                    && (parsedObject[i].ImperialCount == 1)) {
                    var str = parsedObject[i].ImperialWithoutUnit;
                    return retValue(str);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return cellvalue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The information about the line number gives no information if one doesn't know the version of jqGrid. Please include the **version** of jqGrid, which you use and the **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Additionally the test data `gridData` could be the origin of the problem. Could you include the test data, which can be used to reproduce the problem? The best would be the demo (in jsfiddle, for examle).

Comment: Hi Oleg, I'm using jqgrid version 4.6.0, sure i'll add the test data.

Comment: jqGrid 4.6.0 is more as 3.5 years old! It's not supported since a long time. I wrote you additionally that one can analyse the problem only if you post **test data** and more full code (`MyFormatterI`, `MyConverter` and `gridData` are not defined in your current code). I recommend you to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.15.2. It contains full rewritten implementation of `jqPivot`, but the most options are the same. See more details in [the wiki artickle](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9). Finally I think, you should **remove `groupingRemove`** at the end of your code.

Comment: Please, click on the "edit" link below the text of your question and append the text with your code and test data.

Comment: I tried to edit and append i'm frequently getting validation message "It looks like your post is mostly code: please add some more details." So i put it in below answer section.

Comment: I moved your code without any problem. I still repeat that one still can't analyse your problem, because your don't posted enough information to reproduce the problem. In our tests we get no data by `localStorage.getItem('myEventsArray')` (see `MyFormatterI`) and you posted no test data `gridData`. To tell the trust I don't understand your problem in general. Is jqPivot works like you want and you need just prevent grouping? Then you can just add `grouping: false` option (for example near `rowNum: 50`).

Comment: Okay, the problem here is ajax. I have written a separate AJAX call function to get JSON Data (gridData) and assigning to JQGrid Pivot. As i tried directly to make a ajax call like how we do in normal JQGrid, it's not working. So can you please suggest how to make ajax call directly from JQ Pivot grid code.   localStorage.getItem('myEventsArray') is used store  JSON gridData. I have tried with grouping: false in JQ Pivot Grid it didn't work but works fine with JQGrid.

Comment: See **UPDATED 2** part of my answer and [another old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30795988/315935) about Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all some common remarks: jqGrid 4.6.0 is more as 3.5 years old! It's not supported since a long time. I wrote you additionally that one can analyse the problem only if you post **test data** and more full code (`MyFormatterI`, `MyConverter` and `gridData` are not defined in your current code). I recommend you to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.15.2. It contains full rewritten implementation of `jqPivot`, but the most options are the same. See more details in [the wiki artickle](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9).

About your main problem. One can see that the error exists in `groupingRemove` method. Your code use `grid.jqGrid('jqPivot', ...)` to create the grid (the pivot table), but you use later `$('#gridPartNumberSearchGridView')` instead of `grid` later (see calls of `groupingRemove` and `hideCol`). I suppose that `$('#gridPartNumberSearchGridView')` is not jqGrid and thus the call of `groupingRemove` method fails.

**UPDATED:** If you want just prevent grouping, you can add `grouping: false` as additional parameter of jqGrid (near `rowNum: 50` for example).

**UPDATED 2:** Retro version 4.6 uses another order of parameters as free jqGrid (compare [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.pivot.js#L448) with [this one](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.2/js/grid.pivot.js#L828)). If you don't want to upgrade to free jqGrid then you can use `onInitGrid` as a workaround:

```
onInitGrid: function () {
    this.p.grouping = false; // reset grouping before it will be processed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of the error is that the pivot is not created (since of Ajax and little more time to build the pivot) , but before that creation a remove grouping is called, which of course fail. To correct the problem I suggest you to use setTimeout of the last commands - i.e:

```
grid.jqGrid('jqPivot',
...
);  
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#gridPartNumberSearchGridView').jqGrid('groupingRemove');
    $("#gridPartNumberSearchGridView").hideCol("MaterialID");
}, 800);
```

Comment: Yes, This could be the issue. So Is it possible to do ajax call directly through Pivot JQgrid (I have tried it didn't work), Instead of calling externally? Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

We need to remove the grouping from Pivot so we are using that groupingRemove method. Is there an alternative way to get texts instead of using "MyFormatterI" to format the number to a string.
Is it possible to do ajax call directly through Pivot JQgrid (I have tried it didn't work), Instead of calling externally?

```
var MyConverter = function (val) 
{ return (val.replace(/"/g, "")).replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\s/g, '_'); 
}


var MyFormatterI = function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    //debugger;
    var storedString = localStorage.getItem('myEventsArray');
    var parsedObject = JSON.parse(storedString);
    if (options.rowId != "") {
        if (cellvalue === undefined) { return ''; }
        else if (cellvalue.toString().length > 10) { window.IsMultiple = true; return "*"; }
        else if (isNaN(cellvalue) && cellvalue != undefined && parsedObject!=null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < parsedObject.length ; i++) {
                if ((parsedObject[i].MaterialDescription == rowObject["MaterialDescription"])
                    && (parsedObject[i].ZDESMaterialID == rowObject["ZDESMaterialID"])
                    && ((parsedObject[i].DimensionCodeWithDescription.replace(/\s/g, '_') == options.colModel.name) || (parsedObject[i].DimensionCodeWithDescription.replace(/\s/g, '_') + '_sum_0' == options.colModel.name))
                    && (parsedObject[i].ImperialCount == 1)) {
                    var str = parsedObject[i].ImperialWithoutUnit;
                    return retValue(str);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return cellvalue;
        }
    }
}
```

JSON Data (getData):

```
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000079", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;A", DimensionCodes = "AA3", DimensionDescription = "RACE", ImperialWithoutUnit = "1.58", MetricWithoutUnit = "9089", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000079", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "RACE" <br/> AA" }
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000079", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;A", DimensionCodes = "AA6", DimensionDescription = "LARGE", ImperialWithoutUnit = "2.93", MetricWithoutUnit = "9080", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000079", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "LARGE RIB<br/> AA" }
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000069", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;B", DimensionCodes = "AA7", DimensionDescription = "RACE BF", ImperialWithoutUnit = "3.775", MetricWithoutUnit = "19808", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000069", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "RACE BF<br/> AA" }
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000069", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;B", DimensionCodes = "AA9", DimensionDescription = "BORE", ImperialWithoutUnit = "4.1654", MetricWithoutUnit = "1980", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000069", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "BORE<br/> AA" }
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000059", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;C", DimensionCodes = "AA10", DimensionDescription = "SMALL RIB", ImperialWithoutUnit = "8.6250", MetricWithoutUnit = "1909", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000059", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "SMALL RIB<br/> AA" }
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000059", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;C", DimensionCodes = "AA11", DimensionDescription = "WIDTH", ImperialWithoutUnit = "10.8640", MetricWithoutUnit = "2290", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000059", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "WIDTH<br/> AA" }
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000049", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;D", DimensionCodes = "AA12", DimensionDescription = "LARGE WIDTH", ImperialWithoutUnit = "0.1600", MetricWithoutUnit = "9080", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000049", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "LARGE<br/> AA" }
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000049", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;D", DimensionCodes = "AA13", DimensionDescription = "LG HEIGHT", ImperialWithoutUnit = "0.1100", MetricWithoutUnit = "9080", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000049", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "LG<br/> AA" }
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000039", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;E", DimensionCodes = "AA14", DimensionDescription = "RACE FF", ImperialWithoutUnit = "0.1270", MetricWithoutUnit = "9097", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000039", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "RACE FF<br/> AA" }
{ MaterialID = "000000000000000039", MaterialDescription = "38/NC;E", DimensionCodes = "AA15", DimensionDescription = "LG RIB", ImperialWithoutUnit = "0.0500", MetricWithoutUnit = "8090", ZDESMaterialID = "000000000000000039", DimensionCodeWithDescription = "LG LENGTH<br/> AA" }
```

Comment: It looks like the part of your question and **not the answer** on your question. Please, click on the "edit" link below the text of your question and append the text with your code and **test data** (`gridData`). Additionally you should take in consideration that stackoverflow isn't support forum. It shares **common** questions and answers, which should have some value for other developers. Thus you can (and should) simplify your code to make it more readable, but holding the problem, which you have. Your current code uses `localStorage.getItem('myEventsArray')` *without any real value*.

Comment: Okay, I'll again later try to arrange the code in question section, right now it's not happening. Can you please suggest how to do ajax call directly thru JqGrid Pivot code?

Comment: What you post as test data looks not like JavaScript array: you assign properties in a wrong way (you use `MaterialID = "000000000000000079"` instead or `MaterialID: "000000000000000079"`), data contains syntax error s (like `DimensionCodeWithDescription = "RACE" <br/> AA"` instead of probably `DimensionCodeWithDescription = "RACE <br/> AA"`), and so on